# How to justify only a part of a line when the width is not known?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exsheets, wrapfig

One line can be justified as follows: `\makebox[\textwidth][s]{<text>}`. How can I justify only a part of a line when the width is not known? Of course I can adjust the width by trial and error, but don't want to do it.

The use case is described below.

I use `exsheets` package and `wrapfig` to embed figures into exercises.

Exercise 1 represents situation which I normally try to avoid, when there is no text above the figure.

Exercises 2, 3 represent usual situation with one or two lines above the figure. It sometimes looks OK, but always requires a lot of manual work. I need to find where to break the first line and need to make the second line justified with `\makebox[][s]{}`.

I have different types of exercises with different post-code (shown in square brackets).

Using `\hfill` after the exercise number post-code is needed to end the line where normal lines of the paragraph end, otherwise it could end too early. But in some cases `\hfill` produces too much space. Another option is to use `\makebox[<width>][s]{<text>}`, but since question number with a post-code have variable length, I need to adjust  to every question.

If there are more suitable packages and approaches, I'd like to learn about them too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[english,latin]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}  \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{plots/}}

\usepackage[auto-label,counter-within=chapter]{exsheets}

  \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
  \DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runin}{default}{
    runin = true,
    number-pre-code = \hspace{1em},
    number-post-code =~,
    join = { main[hc,vc]number[l,vc](0em,0pt) }
  }

\begin{document}

~

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.39\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.94\linewidth]{3_1_13}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{question}[ID=1]
\texttt{[some text here]}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{question}

\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{
  \begin{question}[ID=2]
  \texttt{[another text]}
  %Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur % is not justified
  %\hfill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur % too much space before "Lorem"
  \makebox[0.675\textwidth][s]{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur} %need to guess the multiplier of the \textwidth

    \begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.39\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.94\linewidth]{3_1_13}
    \end{wrapfigure}
  \noindent \mbox{adipiscing} elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{question}
}

\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{
  \begin{question}[ID=3]
  \texttt{[something else]}
  \hfill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi- % this particular case looks OK, but I'd prefer to use \makebox[<width>][s]{<text>}.

  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{piscing, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et magna. Ut enim}

    \begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.39\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.94\linewidth]{3_1_13}
    \end{wrapfigure}
  \noindent Ut enim ad enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{question}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the issue. Just `\texttt{[something else]}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et magna. Ut enim
  \begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.39\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.94\linewidth, height=1cm]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
  ad enim ad minim veniam` looks ok for me, no `\hfill`, no `\makebox`, no `\noindent`. Just make sure there are no empty lines anywhere that start a new paragraph, then place the wrapfigure somewhere in the text (manual adjustment of the break is still needed).

Comment: Most of the complexity of wrapfig comes from handling multiple paragraphs.  If your questions are a single paragraph each, you could do it all using \parshape and tikz[overlay].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution creates environment `myformat` to place savebox `\illustration` a specified number of lines into the text.

The value 2.2em is approximately the indentation due to the question.  I really didn't want to dig into exsheets or exbook to determine the precise width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[english,latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{plots/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\usepackage[auto-label,counter-within=chapter]{exsheets}

  \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
  \DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runin}{default}{
    runin = true,
    number-pre-code = \hspace{1em},
    number-post-code =~,
    join = { main[hc,vc]number[l,vc](0em,0pt) }
  }

\newsavebox{\illustration}% used to pass image
\newenvironment{myformat}[1]{% #1=line number for start of illustration (1=first)
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-2.2em}% kludge
  \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\illustration-\columnsep}% reduced line width
  \setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr \ht\illustration + \dp\illustration}% total height
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen1/\baselineskip\relax
  \ifdim \dimen1>\the\count1\baselineskip\relax
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \fi
  \count2=0% construct \parshape arguments
  \ifnum #1<2\relax
    \edef\shape{\the\numexpr \count1+1}%
  \else
    \edef\shape{\the\numexpr \count1+#1}%
    \loop\advance\count2 by 1
    \ifnum\count2<#1\relax
      \edef\shape{\shape\space 0pt \the\linewidth}%
    \repeat
    \count2=0
  \fi
  \loop\ifnum\count2<\count1
    \edef\shape{\shape\space 0pt \the\dimen0}%
    \advance\count2 by 1
  \repeat
  \edef\shape{\shape\space 0pt \the\linewidth}%
  \parshape=\shape
  \tikz[overlay]{\path ({\textwidth-\wd\illustration},{\ht\strutbox+\baselineskip-#1\baselineskip})
    node[below right, inner sep=0pt]{\usebox\illustration};}%
  \ignorespaces}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\illustration}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\begin{question}[ID=1] \begin{myformat}{1}
\texttt{[some text here]}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{myformat}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[ID=2] \begin{myformat}{2}
  \texttt{[another text]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
  \end{myformat}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}[ID=3] \begin{myformat}{3}
  \texttt{[something else]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
  \end{myformat}
  \end{question}

\end{document}
```

---

Instead of TikZ one can use

```
  \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\illustration}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\baselineskip-#1\baselineskip-\ht\illustration}[0pt][0pt]%
      {\usebox\illustration}}%
```

---

I developed these as completely separate environments, then figured out how to merge most of the code.

The tricky bit is that `question` contains a `\par` and `\parshape` has to come after the `\par` but before anything else.  So like `wrapfig` I used `\everypar`.

This version no longer needs the indentation for `question`, but instead needs the additional vertical spacing it uses (approximated).

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{plots/}}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[auto-label,counter-within=chapter]{exsheets}

  \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
  \DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runin}{default}{
    runin = true,
    number-pre-code = \hspace{1em},
    number-post-code =~,
    join = { main[hc,vc]number[l,vc](0em,0pt) }
  }

\newsavebox{\illustration}% used to pass image
\newenvironment{leftfigure}[1]{% #1=line number for start of illustration (1=first)
  \setlength{\dimen2}{\dimexpr \wd\illustration+\columnsep}% indentation
  \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr \linewidth-\dimen2}% reduced line width
  \setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr \ht\illustration + \dp\illustration}% total height
  \setlength{\dimen3}{0pt}% image offset
  \commonfigure{#1}}{}

\newenvironment{rightfigure}[1]{% #1=line number for start of illustration (1=first)
  \setlength{\dimen3}{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\illustration}% offset to image
  \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr \dimen3-\columnsep}% reduced line width
  \setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr \ht\illustration + \dp\illustration}% total height
  \setlength{\dimen2}{0pt}% indentation
  \commonfigure{#1}}{}

\newcommand{\commonfigure}[1]{% combine environments
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen1/\baselineskip\relax
  \ifdim \dimen1>\the\count1\baselineskip\relax
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \fi
  \count2=0% construct \parshape arguments
  \ifnum #1<2\relax
    \edef\shape{\the\numexpr \count1+1}%
  \else
    \edef\shape{\the\numexpr \count1+#1}%
    \loop\advance\count2 by 1
    \ifnum\count2<#1\relax
      \edef\shape{\shape\space 0pt \the\linewidth}%
    \repeat
    \count2=0
  \fi
  \loop\ifnum\count2<\count1
    \edef\shape{\shape\space \the\dimen2\space \the\dimen0}%
    \advance\count2 by 1
  \repeat
  \edef\shape{\shape\space 0pt \the\linewidth}%
  \par\noindent\rlap{\hspace{\dimen3}% overlap illustration
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\baselineskip-#1\baselineskip-\ht\illustration-0.8ex}% 0.8ex fudge
      [0pt][0pt]{\usebox\illustration}}%
  \strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}% approximate the vertical spacing for question
  \everypar{\parshape=\shape\everypar{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\illustration}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}%

\begin{rightfigure}{1}
\begin{question}[ID=1]
\texttt{[some text here]}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{rightfigure}

\begin{rightfigure}{2}
\begin{question}[ID=2]
  \texttt{[another text]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{rightfigure}

\begin{rightfigure}{3}
\begin{question}[ID=3]
  \texttt{[something else]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{rightfigure}

\begin{leftfigure}{1}
\begin{question}[ID=4]
\texttt{[some text here]}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{leftfigure}

\begin{leftfigure}{2}
\begin{question}[ID=5]
  \texttt{[another text]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{leftfigure}

\begin{leftfigure}{3}
\begin{question}[ID=6]
  \texttt{[something else]}
  \LipsumPar{1}
\end{question}
\end{leftfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's cool! I like the way it counts `n` lines above the figure and justify them. Simple and clear. My exercises are mostly single paragraph each, indeed. However, with `wrapfig` I can set offset between the image and the text (I'm sure it can be done with `tikz` as well). Also, the new environment `myformat` sets its own indents and the question with `myformat` inside look different (see 1.3 from http://i.imgur.com/WpeHNoA.png). Also, sometimes I want to place the figure in the left part of the question. Otherwise, this approach is much better than with the `wrapfig`.

Comment: You can add more paragraphs so long as the image is entirely contained within the first.  \parshape can be used to adjust the left side as well, I just didn't want to add extra complications.

Comment: could you please modify your answer to tell how: 1. Reserve white space for the figure. 2. Choose to place it left or right. 3. Not to change the formatting of the questions. Then your answer would be a better alternative to `wrapfig`.

Comment: By "reserve white space" are you talking about \intextsep?

Comment: I meant to add a white space border to the figure. I realized that it could be done, for example, with `clip` and `trim` (negative values) options from `graphicx`.

Comment: I already add a \columnsep border to the side.  An additional border is not a problem, if you want to add more arguments.

Comment: I am testing your answer. Unfortunately there is a conflict with `hyperref` package. See screenshot with http://i.imgur.com/91Mk7Ia.png and without `hyperref` http://i.imgur.com/fDUN5gl.png. Apart this, your solution is so much better than what I did with `wrapfig`! Thanks.

Comment: I removed the \rlap to simplify the code, but with hypreref it was causing an extra linebreak.  It should work now.

Comment: sorry, but now your code produces this http://i.imgur.com/DNat6fr.png By the way, I need to replace `\LipsumPar{1}` with `\lipsum[1]` otherwise it produces an error.

Comment: sorry about that.  added the extra } to the wrong line.

Comment: Now it seems perfect. Excellent solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found a bug: http://i.imgur.com/pCuID5z.png . Sometimes when the question goes to the next page the figure stays at previous.

Comment: Yup, wrapfig has the same problem.  Since the figure is overlayed, it is perfectly happy going below the bottom of the text area.  One solution is to avoid the situation using needspace.  Another is to insert wrapfig into the middle of a paragraph (must be after the last word in a line of text).  Which is sort of what you were trying to do originally...

Comment: Thanks, `needspace` solves the problem.